# PHPMailler Erro ao enviar email SMTP connect() failed. UOL HOST

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp, mailer

Olá, estou com um problema referente a conexão com o SMTP da Uol, estou tentando enviar email porém sem nenhum êxito.

```
// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
    $mail->Port = 587 ; 
    $mail->Host = "smtp.dominio.com.br"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)
    $mail->Username = 'email@dominio.com.br'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
    $mail->Password = 'senha'; // Senha do servidor SMTP



    // Define o remetente
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->From = "email@dominio.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
    $mail->FromName = 'nome'; // Seu nome

    // Define os destinatário(s)
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->AddAddress("email@dominio", 'nome');

    //$mail->AddCC('ciclano@site.net', 'Ciclano'); // Copia
    //$mail->AddBCC('fulano@dominio.com.br', 'Fulano da Silva'); // Cópia Oculta



    // Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

    // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->Subject  = "Contato"; // Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Body = "Teste." ;
    $mail->AltBody = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em Texto Plano! \r\n :)";

    // Define os anexos (opcional)
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    //$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/documento.pdf", "novo_nome.pdf");  // Insere um anexo

    // Envia o e-mail
    $enviado = $mail->Send();

    // Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
```

Aqui faço a validação dos IFS.

```
    // Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
    if ($enviado) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=0;URL=../../contato/venda/>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.alert('Em breve responderemos sua mensagem!');</SCRIPT>";


    }else{      



    echo "Erro ao enviar email " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Porém ele retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro.

```
Erro ao enviar email SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: Esta tentando enviar da propria hospedagem do uol ou tentando usar uma conta UOL de fora? Já verificou se não é o firewall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como esta usando a porta `587` provavelmente o servidor deve pedir conexão SSL. Altere o código para:

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Port = 587 ; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.dominio.com.br"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)
$mail->Username = 'email@dominio.com.br'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'senha'; // Senha do servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Porem segundo as [páginas de ajuda do UOL](http://www.uolhost.uol.com.br/faq/email-profissional/tutorial---como-configurar-meu-e-mail-utilizando-a-porta-587-para-envio-de-mensagens.html#rmcl), o SSL não deve ser usado, então recomendo seguir o [tutorial deles](http://www.uolhost.uol.com.br/faq/hospedagem/como-enviar-mensagens-com-php-por-autenticacao-smtp.html#rmcl).

Comment: a porta 587 não é para uso com SSL e sim com TLS. Para SSL a porta seria 465 ou 995.

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcus pela ajuda, foi de muito carinho sua resposta, na data eu acabei utilizando a porta 465. Me desculpe a demora e a falta de tempo em te agradecer.

Answer (score -1):

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);// Não carrega mais automaticamente deve indicar a pasta da classe
try {

```
 //configuracoes do servido UOLHOST (Meu está funcionando normal)
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;//cola 5 ou 6 para ir verificando erro a erro               
$mail->isSMTP();   
$mail->Port = 587;//Não é porta com controle ssl                             
$mail->Host = 'smtp.seu_dominio.com.br';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;             
$mail->Username = 'email@seu_dominio.com.br';//Para o login
$mail->Password = '******';//Para a senha     
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';// deve deixar vazio
```